# Deal with varying class types over stream

Tags: c#, network-programming

I am writing a TCP connection based DLL.
The basic premise is that it can be used by any client and all the client needs to do is supply an ip address and a port number, the dll then takes care of connecting, transmitting messages, detecting disconnections etc.
The dll exposes 3 events `Connected`, `Disconnected` and `MessageReceived` the client simply wires up to these to use it.
The DLL also defines a base `Message`-class which clients can inherit from and then pass their own classes/objects into the DLL for sending/receiving.

In the dll I have defined a `Packet`-class and supporting types:

```
[Serializable]
internal class Packet
{
    private MessageType _type;
    private MessageItem _item;

    public MessageType MYtpe
    {
        get
        {
             return _type;
        }
        set
        {
            _type = value;
        }
    }

     //similar for MessageItem
     // ...
}
```

the enum:

```
public enum MessageType
{
    None,
    PollItem,
    Binary1,
    Binary2
}
```

and base class for the object/class sending:

```
public abstract class MessageItem
{
}
```

My low level, sending the class, code, hidden in the DLL, then is this(without error handling)

```
internal bool SendPacket(Packet p)
{
    bool sentOk = false;
    BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
    try
    {
         bin.Serialize(theNetworkStream, p);
    }
    catch etc..
}
```

`ReadPacket` is basically the reverse of that.

The dll exposes a function for the client to use that constructs the packet and calls above sending function

```
public void SendMessage(MessageType type, MessageItem message)
```

Now for the client.
Because Ive defined 2 binary enum types in the DLL I can use 2 separate classes in my client code.

e.g.

```
public class Employee : MessageItem
{
     string name;
     //etc
}
```

and, say:

```
public class Car : MessageItem
{
    string Model;
    //etc
}
```

This all works and I can receive either of the two types by doing :

```
if(myConnection.NextMessageType() == MessageType.Binary1)
{
     Employee e = (Employee)myConnection.ReadMessage();
}
if(myConnection.NextMessageType() == MessageType.Binary2)
{
    Car c = (Car)myConnection.ReadMessage();
}
```

So long as the client always sends `Employee` types as `binary1` and `Car` as `binary2`.

If I want to send a 3rd type of object/class, at the moment I have to go into the dll, add an enum; `binary3`, rebuild the dll, then I can derive again in my client and use a 3rd `if`-clause in the above receive code.

```
if(myConnection.NextMessageType() == MessageType.Binary3)
{
    Animal a = (Animal)myConnection.ReadMessage();
}
```

So finally onto my question!

is there a way I can avoid having to rebuild the DLL and yet the client can send as many different class types via the DLL as it likes and the send/recieve mechanisms in the DLL (hidden from the client) still work?
I also think the long list of `if messagetype == 1, 2 3` etc is highlighting a bad design but I cant figure what a better design would be.

If you got this far and understand what I'm asking, thanks!  Would really appreciate a solution.

Comment: why do you need to implement that stuff all by yourself? couldn't wcf do the connection/distribution of information-part for you? if so, rather go for multiple methods (eg `HandleEmployee`/`HandleCar`/`HandleAnimal`), so you can be type-safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution would be to change the MessageType enum into a string and get rid of the enum completely. Change:-

```
public void SendMessage(MessageType type, MessageItem message)
```

into just:-

```
public void SendMessage(MessageItem message)
```

and then change the SendPacket to:

```
internal bool SendPacket(Packet p)
{
  bool sentOk = false;
  BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
  try
  {
    bin.write (p.MessageItem.GetType ().Name); // or whatever the write/serialise function is called
    bin.Serialize(theNetworkStream, p);
  }
  catch etc..
}
```

Then, the receiver first reads the string and then uses reflection to create an object of that type, then deserialises into the object, in pseudocode:

```
string message_type = ethernet.readstring ();
Type item_type = convert_name_to_object_type;
ConstructorInfo constructor = item_type.GetConstructor ();
object item = constructor.Invoke ();
ethernet.Deserialise (item);
invoke MessageReceived event (item);
```

That last part could use a `SortedDicationary <message type name, message handler delegate>` to dispatch the message to the right handler (but this forces the handlers to typecast the MessageItem parameter into the correct message type). Alternatively, use reflection again to find a method called "HandleEthernetMessage" that takes one parameter of the type received over the ethernet. `SortedDicationary <message type name, method info>` would be quicker at runtime and overcome the first SortedDictionary issues.

Comment: That seems it could be a goer thanks.  Although I am not sure what function to use for the convert_name_to_object_type bit of your pseudo code.

Comment: @Keith: You could either search the assembly for a type with the same name, or you could pass into the DLL an array of expected types and just search that.

Comment: Hi, Im not entirely sure what you mean by "searching the assembly",  can the dll search the calling exe's assembly?  Sorry if im being a bit dim.  Its just that the derived classes will only be in the exe's assembly, not in the dll assembly so I am not sure the dll could search outside its own scope so to speak?  Maybe it can?

Comment: @Keith: Yes, they can. Use `Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly (); Type [] types = assembly.GetTypes ();` or `Type type = assembly.GetType (typename);` or `Type type = Type.GetType (typename);` For speed, you may want to do the first one once and cache the types you find that are derived from your message base type, or call the latter for message types you've not seen before and save the result.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the caching method a go.  I may be back with more q's later!  :)

Comment: I dont even need to write the name of the type in the send packet do I?  The read packet can use reflection to find the type name.